# Create Subdomain on BigRock with Godaddy hosting

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, cloudflare

I have a domain on BigRock and hosting on GoDaddy. I am also using CloudFlare in between. Now I need to add a subdomain on BigRock which should also point to a subdomain on GoDaddy.

I have created a Subdomain on GoDaddy hosting successfully. However actions might also be needed on BigRock and Cloudflare.

I tried to add a CName record on Bigrock looking at some tutorials online. But it said HostName and Value cannot be same. There's very small help available on adding subdomain on BigRock where as for GoDaddy is was easy.

I need the steps needed to complete what I am trying to do.

Comment: Where are the last nameservers of your domain?

Comment: @ardacar It's on BigRock.. I have added cloudflare's namespaces at Bigrock.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've got a standard Cloudflare setup, where you have configured the name servers in BigRock to point to Cloudflare's.

In this case you just need to add the subdomain on [Cloudflare's DNS settings page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-Managing-DNS-records-in-Cloudflare).

Depending on what options GoDaddy offer for pointing domains to your hosted sub-domain, your choice of entry will vary.

I'd recommend setting it up as a CNAME record if possible, pointing to the GoDaddy subdomain, as this will give you slightly more flexibility if GoDaddy need to move your server at any time - this would typically mean you wouldn't need to update the DNS. However I'm not sure how likely this is, so an A record mapping to the IP address may be fine.

In either case, you can then choose between "proxied" where Cloudflare provides full CDN services, etc ) or not.

You shouldn't need to make any further changes in BigRock.

Comment: Why CName not an A record? Because before reading your answer, as trial and error, I added an A record and the site is working.

Comment: Great - I'd not looked into GoDaddy's options for handling Subdomains, etc. on their hosting options - some providers don't offer IP based options there, but if GoDaddy do, then go for it. CNames have the slight advantage that they can offer a bit more flexibility in terms of the underlying infrastructure - if GoDaddy need to move your server for some reason, you may need to update the DNS to the new IP address, but if they've provided a generic host name, using a CNAME to that would typically mean you wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Create your subdomain in godaddy then point it in your cloudflare configuration also from your hosting (BigRock)..
if you don't need seperate setting for your subdomain
don't touch unnecessarily in your bigrock domain settings.